# "Unicode Blank Symbol Rendering Issue after Updating to Python 3.11 and Django 4.1.7"

Tags: html, unicode, django-forms, upgrade, python-3.11

I'm facing an issue with rendering a Unicode blank symbol in my Django project after upgrading to Python 3.11 and Django 4.1.7. Previously, I was using the following code snippet in my `MyForm` class:

```py
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        labels = {
            "test": "&#8203;",
        }
```

The purpose of using "​" was to maintain formatting due to its equivalent height as a normal character.

However, since updating to Python 3.11 and Django 4.1.7, the Unicode blank symbol is no longer displayed correctly. Instead, it's being shown as the string "​".

I'd appreciate any insights into how I can resolve this issue. Thank you i```n advance for your help.

Best regards,
tux

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is very easy, just use real python unicode coding instead of the html unicode. The reason why it crashed was, that Django is rendering the & to &. So the ​ is a  &#8203; and the browser writes this sting: ​

here my solution which works:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        labels = {
            "test": "\u200B",
        }
```